# How can I connect VSCode remote debugger to a custom websocket server?

Tags: node.js, websocket, vscode-debugger

I have a NodeJS based web application that has the debug inspector exposed via public websocket endpoint. For security this endpoint requires authentication during connection initialization. How can I get VS Code's remote debugger to be able to connect to this custom websocket server? If that can't work, is it possible to write an extension that establishes the connection, performs auth and then hands the connection off to the built-in NodeJS remote debugger?

Comment: you could also potentially [raise an issue ticket asking about this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=other.md&title=). If you do, please ping me here with a link to your issue ticket.